# We want to add to the delivery price depending on a date chosen

Tags: bigcommerce

We would like to be able to add a extra price to the shipping (delivery) if a certain date was chosen. For example, if someone chooses 2/14/16 on the product page, we want to add $5 to the set BC delivery price in the checkout. Can this be done?

We already have a date picker communicating with BC that blocks delivery dates and sets daily cut off time for local delivery.

Comment: Please add some code what you’ve already tried. We do not simply write your code.

Comment: He is just asking if it can be done. Upvote.

Comment: Thanks Sudo. - Kitmedia, why would I want you to write my code? I have devs for that.

Comment: downvoting for cockiness, your devs can figure it out

Comment: Hahah I am so lost here. Kitt said they're not writing our code and asked why I'd ask them to, since we already have people who do that and now I'm cocky? hahaha ok :)  - What an odd help site where you come for help and people chastise you.

Comment: Haha, I'm sorry Brandon, you're right, I think I was just projecting my own insecurities on you. I just ate a pint of ice cream with my own added oreos (double stuffed, of course (do people buy the regular one's still?)), and I'm feeling quite better now. How about we all just relax and have a fresh start here... Aye?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the order total at the point of checkout, except for two exceptions:

1. Coupon
2. Shipping

Since a coupon is used for decreasing the order total, this won't fit your use case.
So then I would recommend you somehow tie this $5 charge into a shipping method, and then select that shipping method with JS somehow, or hide the others. For example, copy your current shipping methods and add a $5 handling fee to them, and then hide your original methods when the specific date is chosen. Vice versa.

Comment: Since the date appears to be chosen on the product page, it would actually need to read data out of the cart which isn't exposed when shipping selections are being made.

Comment: Ah yes, need my glasses.